# Product measure on two uncountable well-ordered sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\leq)$ be an uncountable well-ordered set such that for any $y\in X,\{x\in X:x<y\}$ is countable. For any $A\subset X$, let $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mu(A)=1$ if $X\setminus A$ is countable. Then $\mu$ is a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra. Define $T$, the "ordinal triangle", by $T:=\{(x,y)\in X\times X:y<x\}$. Then
\begin{equation}
\iint1_T(x,y)d\mu(y)d\mu(x)=0\neq1=\iint1_T(x,y)d\mu(x)d\mu(y).
\end{equation}

This contradicts the following theorem.

**Product Measure Existence Theorem** Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ be two $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. In $X\times Y$ let $\mathcal{R}$ be the collection of all "rectangles" $B\times C$ with $B\in\mathcal{B}$ and $C\in\mathcal{C}$. For such sets let $\rho(B\times C):=\mu(B)\nu(C)$, where (in this case) we set $0\cdot\infty:=\infty\cdot0:=0$. Let $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{C}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{R}$. Then $\rho$ extends uniquely to a measure on $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{C}$ such that for all $E\in\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathcal{C}$,
\begin{equation}
\rho(E)=\iint1_E(x,y)d\mu(x)d\nu(y)=\iint1_E(x,y)d\nu(y)d\mu(x).
\end{equation}

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to argue that the set $T$ in question actually belongs to the relevant $\sigma$-algebra in the first place. In this case, that algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X^2$ generated by sets of the form $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are each either countable or co-countable subsets of $X$. This is something you've implicitly assumed, but it requires proof - and in fact is not true! $T$ is not in the (very "slim") $\sigma$-algebra on $X^2$ generated by the "countable-or-co-countable" $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. So there's no contradiction.

(Proving that $T$ is not in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ generated by the products of countable-or-co-countable subsets of $X$ is a good exercise. Here's a hint: say that $U\subseteq X^2$ is *boring* iff there is some cocountable $A\subseteq X$ such that $A^2\subseteq U$ or $A^2\cap U=\emptyset$. Show that the boring sets form a $\sigma$-algebra. Note that the "$\sigma$-" part is of course crucial: $T$ is an *uncountable* union of rectangles in $\mathcal{A}$, but that doesn't make $T$ an element of $\mathcal{A}$.)